# Extending the ?: Operator?

Tags: c#, operators

```
 Name = (src.Client.Account.Rank > 65 ?  src.Client.Account.Rank > 2  ? "$" : "@" : "") + src.Name,
```

This is my current coding for it. I'm trying to get it so if rank is more than 65 show `"$"`, if it's more then 2 but not more than 65, then show `"@"`, and if it's neither, then show `""`.

This is for a online game, and this is client side with C#. I'm still a noob, so I'm not exactly sure what all you need to fix this.

As you can see I was trying to turn then `?:` operator into a ``??:: or something, I tried using `,` because I saw someone post that, but I guess it doesn't work for C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this one will work as you want

```
Name = ((src.Client.Account.Rank > 65) ? "$" : ((src.Client.Account.Rank > 2) ? "@" : "")) + src.Name,
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Name = (src.Client.Account.Rank > 65 
       ?  "$" : 
       (src.Client.Account.Rank > 2  ? "@" : "")) + src.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is nested logic involved, an `if` statement is arguably more readable than the ternary operator:

```
string prefix = null;
if (src.Client.Account.Rank > 65)
    prefix = "$";
else if (src.Client.Account.Rank > 2)
    prefix = "@";

Name = string.Concat(prefix, src.Name);
```